# Can/should I make a junction from C:\Program Files or DriverStore to my D drive?

Tags: windows-10, mklink

I've got this really annoying setup on my laptop, where I've got a teeny little 128 GB SSD for my system drive, and a really generous 1TB HDD. Which does me no freakin' good when a whole bunch of applications *insist* on being installed on the C drive. So now, with 5GB left on my SSD, I did a disk analysis with WinDirStat and found:

- 16.6 GB in `C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore`
- 15.8 GB in `C:\Program Files (x86)`
- 15.4 GB in `C:\Program Files`

I would dearly love to move all of the above onto my D drive, and make a junction using `mklink` so that all future apps that try to force themselves onto my miniscule SSD get ju-jitsu'd onto the D drive.

BUT...is it safe, or even possible, to do so?

The `Program Files` folders don't appear to allow deletion or renaming (at least, not through the front door). I know I could do each app independently, but that's a lot of effort; I'd rather do everything in one fell swoop. And I don't know enough about that `DriverStore` folder to feel confident that moving it onto the D drive won't cause damage.

Advice, please?

Comment: 16GB in `DriverStore` seems extremely excessive.  Try [Driver Store Explorer](https://github.com/lostindark/DriverStoreExplorer) and see if you can just delete some.

Comment: @lx07 Thanks for the tip. I downloaded it, but I only managed to clean up about 800 MB of old drivers. Nvidia is the guilty party here; it's hogging nearly 15GB by itself.